# Adding Html Action Links to a List in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a navigational menu for my project which uses the ASP.NET framework and C# programming language. My solution is to create a widget which can populate a partial view when called from the master page.
In the widget's action method, how do I add Links or Controller-Action combinations to the ViewDataDictionary?

--- Edit : Here is my code, after your suggestion

```
public class NavController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Menu()
    {           
        List<ActionLink> navLinks = new List<ActionLink>();
        navLinks.Add(new ActionLink() { Text = "Home", ActionName = "Index", ControllerName = "Home" });
        return View(navLinks);          
    }
}
```

The partial view file looks like the following:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Controls.ActionLink>>" %>

<% foreach(var link in Model) { %>
<%= link %>
<%}  %>
```

But the output of all this is simply 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Controls.ActionLink' and not the link which I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actionlink is a mvc control of some sort that would be the result of parsing a tag and would then be added to the controls collection of the page.

You have 2 options to achieve your goal, pass in the complete links ( i.e. the fully formed anchor tag ) which you could generate in your controller using Html.ActionLink( linkText, actionName) or pass the details of the link to your partial and use those details to generate the links ( i.e. pass an enumeration of elements containing the details of your links ).

Personally I prefer the second approach as it separates the navigation logic from the rendering.

Somewhere in your code ...

```
public class NavigationLink
{
  public string Text;
  public string Controller;
  public string Action;
  // ... any other properties you want to pass
}
```

Somewhere in your controller ...

```
public ActionResult Menu
{
  var links = new List<NavigationLink>
  {
    new NavigationLink
    {
      Text = "Home",
      Controller = "Home",
      Action = "Index"
    },
    new NavigationLink
    {
      Text = "Logout",
      Controller = "Authentication",
      Action = "Logout"
    }
  };

  return View( links );
}
```

Somewhere in your view ...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<NavigationLink>>" %>

<% foreach(var link in Model) { %>
<%= Html.ActionLink( link.Text, link.Action, link.Controller ) %>
<%}  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you're looking for?

```
  List<ActionLink> actions = new List<ActionLink>(); //or = ViewData["actions"] for adding
  actions.Add(new ActionLink() { ActionName = "actionname", ControllerName = "controller" });
  ViewData["actions"] = actions;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried your method but I'm sure I'm still doing something wrong here. Please see above.

Comment: Use link's RenderControl method or ToString - I can't test now. Lets check out yourself which one renders the link.

Comment: Thanks for you time, which is unfortunately scarce at my end as well. I'll explore this later after the demo tomorrow when I refactor other sections of code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a straightforward approach by adding ViewData directly to the dictionary.

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
 ViewData.Add("one", "<a href=\"../Home/Index\">Home</a>");
 ViewData.Add("two", "<a href=\"../Account/LogOff\">Log Off</a>");

 return View();
}
```

In the partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<ul>
<% foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in ViewData) { %>

<li>
    <%=pair.Value %>
</li>

<%}  %>
</ul>
```

May not be the most clever way to do this, but it works.